# Can Parse.com be used to trigger in-app messages?

Tags: parse-platform

Can Parse.com be used to trigger in-app messages? In addition to push notifications, we want to make sure users who are currently using the app can get notified of new messages, comments, likes, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure. As your users are in the app, the notifications will not be seen as banners or anything else on the screen. But nonetheless, the device gets them. Just handle them and add some kind of badge on an icon.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {     
  //handle it here
}
```